# Unknown triangle property involving $ab+bc+ca$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, locus

Three lines intersect forming a triangle of sides $(a, b, c) $.

Let $ab+bc+ca= \rho^2;$ Can we try to define a new third property along with $(r,R)$(in-circle, circumcircle radii) involving $\rho?$

Motivation is to find a new locus/curve with a geometric property  alongwith $ (r,R) $ as another circle or curve. We naturally look to the coefficients in:

$$ (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)= s^3-s^2(a+b+c)+s(ab+bc+ca=\rho^2)-abc $$

Relation $ r^2+ 4rR + s^2 = =\rho^2$ is given in g.kov's comment.

Candidate characteristic "radius" length properties are:

$$[\dfrac{\rho^2}{r},\dfrac{\rho^2}{s},\dfrac{\rho^2}{R}]=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$$

$b_2$ curve is easy to calculate. It equals twice base of triangle $c$ between "foci" when sides $(a,b)$ describe a particular [Oval of Cassini$ (e=2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval)

$$\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}=c\rightarrow ab=c^2;\;(ab+bc+ca)/s= 2 c ;\;$$

[image: (ab+bc+ca)/2=c]

Comment: What is P in this setting?

Comment: Since $ab+bc+ca=s^2+r^2+4rR$,
you are looking
for a curve(s) somehow associated with a triangle,
which limits the triangles 
to have a constant sum of ratios 
$\tfrac sr+\tfrac rs+\tfrac{4R}s$, right?

Comment: Indeed, looking in the triangle what geometrical significance the sum  of these ratios has to the associated new circle or curve.

Comment: For an equilateral triangle $\rho= 2 h$ or double its height $h$.

Comment: @g.kov : After posting seeking a ratio after some thought  I changed the sought function more aptly to  be a dimensioned linear quantity in line with $(R,r)$. Not to be viewed as changing the goal..as anyhow our search is for an unknown. Hope it is okay and in order. Regards